# Select Box alignment within a DIV

Tags: css

I'm trying to identify why this select box can't be aligned within the same row. I played around with the CSS properties but still couldn't identify the root cause.

Which CSS property might be influencing this behavior? I've modified several properties related to Padding/Margin and still nothing.

I'm using Material Dashboard template.

Problem only happens when it's a select box. Input boxes works fine.

Here's a snapshot:

[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fblY.png)

```
<div class="card-body">

                                        <div class="row">

                                            <div class="col-md-3">

                                                <div class="form-group">

                                                    <label class="control-label">Status</label>

                                                    <select class="form-control" name="status" id="status">

                                                        <option value="">Selecione..</option>

                                                        <option value="1" <?= (isset($dataUpdate->send_status) && $dataUpdate->send_status == "1" ? "selected" : null) ?>> Em conferência </option>

                                                        <option value="2" <?= (isset($dataUpdate->send_status) && $dataUpdate->send_status == "2" ? "selected" : null) ?>> Aguardando Pagamento </option>

                                                        <option value="3" <?= (isset($dataUpdate->send_status) && $dataUpdate->send_status == "3" ? "selected" : null) ?>> Pago </option>

                                                        <option value="4>" <?= (isset($dataUpdate->send_status) && $dataUpdate->send_status == "4" ? "selected" : null) ?>> Em Aprovação </option>

                                                        <option value="5" <?= (isset($dataUpdate->send_status) && $dataUpdate->send_status == "5" ? "selected" : null) ?>> Processando </option>

                                                        <option value="6" <?= (isset($dataUpdate->send_status) && $dataUpdate->send_status == "6" ? "selected" : null) ?>> Enviado </option>

                                                        <option value="7" <?= (isset($dataUpdate->send_status) && $dataUpdate->send_status == "7" ? "selected" : null) ?>> Entregue </option>

                                                    </select>
                                                    
                                                </div>

                                            </div>

                                            <!--/span-->

                                            <div class="col-md-3">

                                                <div class="form-group">

                                                    <label class="control-label">Data do Envio</label>

                                                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="send_date" value="<?= (isset($dataUpdate->send_date) ? date_fmt($dataUpdate->send_date, "Y-m-d") : null) ?>">
                                                    
                                                </div>

                                            </div>

                                            <!--/span-->

                                            <div class="col-md-6">

                                                <div class="form-group">

                                                    <label class="control-label">Código de Rastreio</label>

                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="code_tracker" value="<?= (isset($dataUpdate->send_code_tracker) ? $dataUpdate->send_code_tracker : null) ?>" placeholder="EX: US989DKI56">

                                                </div>

                                            </div>

                                            <!--/span-->

                                        </div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Can you create a sandbox / snippet for this?

It is very difficult to debug, from the markup you posted, everything looks fine.

Comment: A closing *</div>* is missing in this code.

Comment: A typ error in `<option value="4>"` ?